# The use of the nonword "unscavanged"

Tags: creative-writing

I'm wondering if it's okay to use a word this way if it's used in a more poetic tone and less informative: "Rare valuables and homes unscavanged beckon ignorant survivors but most know a trip up the valley is never worth the trouble it brings."
The word in question is "unscavanged".

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Where does the quotation come from? Do you mean “unscavenged”? We try to avoid matters of opinion so you may find your question becomes closed.

Comment: Unscavenged isn't in most dictionaries, but I can see it used in scientific papers, e.g. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/19384115/ I don't know how to judge if it's OK to use it - why would or wouldn't it be ok? Is it for an assignment (where you might get marked down for using a word that's not in a dictionary) or a piece of creative writing for your own pleasure? Are you writing for a publication with a style guide? Are you worried about spelling? As Anton says, it seems a matter of opinion not a question with a real answer, unless you have some more specific issue with it.

Comment: Okay? You can use _wgehftme_ in your own writing. Okay by what standards? // Non-words and even candidates (which _wgehftme_ certainly isn't) are off-topic on ELU, which looks at issues that are (reasonably) readily researchable.